# Why object in terminal velocity doesnt stop

Tags: forces

In termianl velocity,the force due to weight is equal to force due to air resistance so why doesnt the object stop. Of course I know it won't stop but I want an explination in terms of physics. As what I understand is when 2 forces in opposite directions are equal, there is no movement. Thanks

Comment: [Newton's second law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion#Newton's_second_law)

Comment: *As what I understand is when 2 forces in opposite directions are equal, there is no movement.* Where'd you learn that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When two forces in opposite directions are equal, there is no *acceleration*. That doesn't mean that there is no movement. It simply means that there is no change in velocity.

Comment: So, If an object is moving at terminal velocity and then opens the parachute, the air resistance is higher than the weight so why doesnt he go upwards.

Comment: @OmarMagdy See question linked in comment by Chris above.

Comment: @OmarMagdy If you were moving at the same speed as the falling object, you _would_ see it go upwards. If you were on the ground, you would see it slow down. In both of these cases, the fact that there is a net force on the object means that it accelerates, which means that its velocity changes. If its velocity is already zero in your reference frame, that means it starts to move. If its velocity is nonzero in your reference frame, that means it speeds up, slows down, or changes direction.